# Read external configuration file from jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, spring-boot

I'm building a jar (with Maven and Spring Boot) that needs to read an external property file. It should be in the same directory of the running jar (or in a relative path to it, like `./config.properties` or `./conf/config.properties`.

Right now I can read successfully the embedded jar in the resources directory but if I try to read it from the local directory the InputStream is going to be `null`.

I've tried adding the local dir `.` to the classpath (unpacking the jar I can see it in the Class-Path entry) but it didn't worked.

This is what I tried:

```
InputStream in = PropertiesLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")
InputStream in = PropertiesLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("./config.properties")
InputStream in = PropertiesLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./config.properties")
InputStream in = PropertiesLoader.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./config.properties")
```

In my pom.xml I have this entry to add the local dir to the classpath:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>bla.bla.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've also tried the `user.dir` property but without succes.

This should be "easy" but I'm quite lost.

Comment: cmiiw, you're trying to read a file form the same directory with your jar right? if yes, then I guess the `new FileInputStream("./file_name.txt")` should suffice right?

Comment: Do you make use of an `application.properties` file in the JAR? Is the `config.properties` file outside the JAR an override?

Comment: @kucing_terbang hm.. I got a FileNotFound..

Comment: @geoand nope, I'm not using the application.properties. Should be an override but just to see if it's going to work I've changed the name of the one inside the jar to "default.properties".

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot can do all the heavy lifting of reading property files for you with zero configuration. There is no need to manually read the property files. See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) part of the documentation for the details.

To make your life as easy as possible, I propose the following (which is actually the Spring Boot default strategy):

Have an `application.properties` file in `src/resources` which contains the default values for all properties.
In the environment where the jar will be run, have a file named `application.properties` either in same directory as the jar, or in a subdirectory named `config`.

Once you do that, each property will be available in Spring Beans via the `@Value` annotation or the `@ConfigurationProperties` type handling.

Also note that you can name the properties file something other than `application.properties` as long as you set `--spring.config.name=config` when the jar is run, for example `java -jar somejar.jar --spring.config.name=config`

Comment: Hm, thanks. I already had a look to it. I wasn't really excited to use injection for such a thing but I'll give it a try. So it seems there's no way to tell Spring Boot to use a different filename (a part from telling him with that property while running)?

Comment: You could also to use the standard Spring `@PropertySource`. However I suggest sticking with the conventions and do use property injection. They will make your life easier and make the application far more testable that hand rolled property-file reading

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and it worked succesfully:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("./test/application.properties"));
```

or spring way

```
Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(new FileSystemResource("./test/application.properties"));
```

They both do the same trick, second is safe, so you dont need to close the inputstream.

The trick is, you need to crate the `test` folder same level with the `src` to make it work with maven. So when you have the jar, you can create test folder and put file in it.

Tested also as a jar.